# A std::max, but for template parameters

Tags: c++, templates

I'm finding myself in need of a template class that finds the maximum of two constant values at compile time; something like this:

```
template<enum_t e1, enum_t e2>
struct max_of { static const enum_t value = SOMEHOW_MAX(e1, e2); };
```

where `enum_t` is an enumerated type, and `max_of<x, y>::value` should equal the maximum of `x` and `y`.   So the question is: what to use in place of `SOMEHOW_MAX`?  I am constrained against using c++14 features, so it can't just be `std::max`, because that can't compare template parameter values at compile time.  If the cardinality of `enum_t` is reasonably small, one possible way to implement `max_of` is via template specializations, like so:

```
template<>
struct max_of<E_FIRST, E_SECOND> { static const enum_t value = E_SECOND; };
```

which does work, but clearly becomes rather verbose even for a small number of `enum_t` values.  Is there some way to get the template system to take the maximum programatically?

Comment: What is wrong with [`std::max`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/max)?  It is `constexpr`.

Comment: Since c++14 you can use `std::max`

Comment: Looks like boost does provide [something along these lines|http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_42_0/libs/integer/doc/html/boost_integer/minmax.html]

Comment: You can use `std::underlying_type` (C++11) to safely cast your enum type to a numeric type and compare that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In C++14 you should just use `std::max`. If, however, C++14 is off-limits, following simple code should help:

```
template<enum_t A, enum_t B> 
struct max_of {
    enum { value = A > B ? A : B};
};
```

Answer (score 3):

You have two solutions. You can use a simple comparison and using the ternary operator to select the biggest value, or you can use `std::max`, which will work for c++14 and up.

`std::max` solution

```
template<enum_t e1, enum_t e2>
struct max_of {
    static constexpr auto value = std::max(e1, e2);
};
```

manual solution:

```
template<enum_t e1, enum_t e2>
struct max_of {
    static constexpr auto value = e1 > e2 ? e1 : e2;
};
```

You can alternatively implement your own max function to complete the lack of a `constexpr` one in c++11:

```
template<typename T> 
constexpr const T& max(const T& a, const T& b) {
    return (a < b) ? b : a;
}
```